# Disable Unique Partition Attribution schema validation in java

Tags: java, xml, xsd, sax

I am transforming an XML into another XML using dom4j. Now I need to validate the transformed XML with an external XSD file which I m doing through SAXParserFactory.

When I run the program, there is an exception with message

> violation of Unique Particle Attribution

How can I disable this Unique Particle Attribution in my program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely this should address your problem:

http://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/features.html#validation.schema-full-checking

Comment: Seeking help from the suggested page, I am writing now: SAXParserFactory valfactory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance(); SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"); valfactory.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/validation/schema-full-checking", false); valfactory.setSchema(schemaFactory.newSchema(new File("XSD/myXSD.xsd"));                                            But still it is giving:                    org.xml.sax.SAXParseException  with message "violate "Unique Particle Attribution"  Please advice where I am going wrong. Thanks !!!

Comment: I was working applying it on incorrect object. Now I am applying it on schemaFactory, & it is workign fine. Thanks !!!